# How Parse JSON from API

Tags: ios, json, swift

i know to much ask like this. i already searching but not match with my problems.

oke i will try explain with my code

i have data API Like this

```
["profile": {
accountId = 58e470a0c50472851060d083;
androidDeviceId = "[\"3453247ddcf3f809\"]";
androidVersion = 21;
appId =     (
    "c46b4c10-62ce-11e6-bdd4-59e4df4b8410",
    "fac915f0-fe2b-11e6-9dfb-55339bd7be35"
);
appVersion = "v5.1.0";
avatar = "https://account.8villages.com/uploads/images/5/1491366164_bnx1t0rudi.jpg";
birthDate = "12/03/1994";
"channel-group" = android;
communityId = 553e09b251906884443eff85;
coordinates =     {
    coordinates =         (
        "106.9602383333333",
        "-6.249333333333334"
    );
    type = Point;
};
crop = "";
crops = "<null>";
customerId = 5369bd85cae84d0e03246a7c;
dateSubmitted =     {
    iso = "2017-04-05T04:20:48.483Z";
    timestamp = 1491366048;
};
fullName = "Megi Fernanda";
gender = "Laki-laki";
homeAddress = Payakumbuah;
location = "Kota Payakumbuh";
moderation =     {
    at =         {
        iso = "2017-04-05T04:20:48.483Z";
        timestamp = 1491366048;
    };
    by = auto;
    status = moderated;
};

skill = "Budidaya pertanian";
state = "Sumatera Barat";
storeType = "";
subdistrict = "Payakumbuh Barat";
totalConversations =     {
    articles = 0;
    forums = 0;
    questions = 2;
    responses = 0;
    storeItems = 1;
};
type = users;
university = "Politeknik Negeri Pertanian Payakumbuh";
}, "accessToken": {
key = "lH5aYvnp2JAZ6zoKQK4mpfsxCI0.";
secret = "yfZfTZbsaVIhKCbksGHQnPcPg9mKtoRAKyvjg_cgMeo.";
}]
```

i already can got **fullName, Addres, Skill State etc**

```
if let profile = json["profile"] as? NSDictionary {
         let name = profile["fullName"]
         let alamat = profile["Skill"]
 }
```

but i don't know how to get atribut in **totalConversation** like **question, storeItems, points**

```
skill = "Budidaya pertanian";
state = "Sumatera Barat";
storeType = "";
subdistrict = "Payakumbuh Barat";
totalConversations =     {
    articles = 0;
    forums = 0;
    questions = 2;
    responses = 0;
    storeItems = 1;
};
```

i tried like

**let profile = json["profile"]["totalConversation"] as? NSDictionary**

error sign : Type 'any?' has no subscript members

Comment: Dupe.  Searching for "Type 'Any?' has no subscript members" here turns up over 150 hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got that error because `json["profile"]` is `Any` type and it doesn't have any `subscript`. So you need to cast `json["profile"]` to a dictionary, `[String: Any]` is dictionary type in Swift.

```
if let profile = json["profile"] as? [String: Any] {
    if let totalConversations = profile["totalConversations"] as? [String: Any] {
        let questions = totalConversations["questions"] as? Int
    }
}
```

Comment: yaaap this is work. i already tried before